# How JMeter tests web application

Tags: jmeter, load-testing

I made load test on my web application with JMeter using HTTP Proxy. In HTTP Request I insert some data which I want to change. After load test when I go to the web page the page was without changes and I get all results(graph and table). Is that test real or not? Because was without page (data) changes?

Comment: What data did you want to change on the web page? Give an example. JMeter shows the request params and response HTML for each request. So check that too.

Comment: I have server login page witch uses javascript input field. And in (View Results Tree)/(Response Data) a get response the same as when I disable JavaScript in Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

Use the "tree view" LISTENER to see what request you sent to your web application. That will tell you if Jmeter was sending the new data, or just sending what you recorded. If Jmeter sent new data, then your application probably has a problem.  If Jmeter sent the old recorded data, then you  need to update your script by going to the request and changing the parameters.

Comment: The data requests is the same that I recorded, but the URL parameter is changing on every requests.